# My svg image icons is hiding behind my css container

Tags: html, css

Firstly i'm new to web development and this is my first challenge attempting to Flyo data storage. I need help as i got the margins somewhat right for containers. But im trying to make my icon svg image appear at the front and i can't do it. Please help to review my code!
[Index. html in atom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1frXI.png)[Css Atom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yswOd.png)
[Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX9wP.png)

Comment: Did you try `z-index:9;`?

Comment: No i never used that before. But i tried display: inline-block;
    margin: 0; in my (css body) & this is my index.html code: body>
  <div class="wide-container">
    <div class="container">
        <img class="desktop-bg" src="images/desktop-bg.png" alt="desktop-img">
      </div>
      <div class="icons">
        <img class="document" src="icons/icon-document.svg" alt="document-img">
        <img class="folder" src="icons/icon-folder.svg" alt="folder-img">
        <img class="upload" src="icons/icon-upload.svg" alt="upload-img">
    </div>
 It worked but i dont know why??

Answer (score 0):

> CSS:

```
img .classname {
  z-index: 1
}
```

**Explanation:** The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.
An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

[Read more:](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: No i never used img. classname { z-index: 1} I don't know how. But i tried display: inline-block; margin: 0; in my (css body) & this is my index.html code: body> <div class="wide-container"> <div class="container"> <img class="desktop-bg" src="images/desktop-bg.png" alt="desktop-img"> </div> <div class="icons"> <img class="document" src="icons/icon-document.svg" alt="document-img"> <img class="folder" src="icons/icon-folder.svg" alt="folder-img"> <img class="upload" src="icons/icon-upload.svg" alt="upload-img"> </div> It worked but i dont know why??